# socket recv function not returning updated value

Tags: c, linux, sockets, recv

Trying to create socket application using c (Linux) to constantly fetch data from a server
For this I have created a loop and inside it the routine connects , send a command, receive some data and close the socket.
It works fine for the first interaction but looks like the recv function failing to update the buffer variable from second iteration and others.

Tried to use the `memset` function to clear but that clears the variable and it comes always blank after first iteration

Any ideas ?

Here is the example of code I´m using

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    char *message , server_reply[2000];
    struct sockaddr_in server;  
    int socket_desc;
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);

    if (socket_desc == -1)
    {
        printf("Could not create socket");
    }

    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.10");
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons( 23 );

    int count = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("\nContador >> %i\n", count);
        count++;  
        connect(socket_desc , (struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server));
        send(socket_desc , "command\r" , 2 , 0); 
        sleep(5);

//Receive a reply from the server
        recv(socket_desc, server_reply , 100 , 0);
        printf(server_reply); /// This always shows the same values as the first iteraction 
        sleep(10);
        close(socket_desc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know how much data recv returned?  You aren't checking.

Comment: nope, never thought it would be necessary as at the first loop iteration was getting the right command reply. why would I need that  ?

Comment: because return values give you information about what's happening. You should be checking the return values of `connect`, `send` and `close` as well... and if any of those return an error code, check `errno` to see what caused the error.

Comment: so, nothing wrong with logic ? only error handling ?

Comment: Not checking the return value of `recv()` is a logic flaw, not (just) an error-handling flaw.  Short reads are a *bona fide* non-error possibility.  And your question supposes that error-handling flaws should generally be accounted distinct from logic flaws, which is not self-evident.

Comment: Stream sockets don't keep track of message boundaries, there's no guarantee that `recv()` will return exactly one message.

Comment: It doesn't add a null terminator to the data, so you can't use `printf()` on it. Also, the first argument to `printf()` should be a format string, not the data you want to print.

Comment: jyst only put recv print and sleep insude loop. remove above commands.   close socket just before end of main return 0 statement. put connct send sleep above for.

Comment: a better  way is just put connect above for and close before return 0. we dont need to connect in each itteration . a connected socket remains working untill closing it.

Comment: @EsmaeelE I tried using connect and close out from for but if for some reason the server get unavailable, the program quits

Comment: comment loop and test it one time. first check send section is it work. if true add recv

Comment: @Barmar: you CAN use `printf()`, if you pass the return value of `recv()` to `printf()` so it knows where to stop, eg: `int res = recv(..., server_reply, ...); if (res > 0) { printf("%.*s", res, server_reply); ... }` Then it doesn't need a null terminator

Comment: @RemyLebeau Anything is possible, that doesn't make it reasonable. The only excuse for that would be if you can't make the buffer big enough to allow for adding the null terminator.

Comment: What should I use @Barmar? Instead printf? I'm on my using that to see the recv output

Comment: Add a null terminator to the end of `server_reply` and then use `printf("%s\n", server_reply)`

Comment: Or just use `write(STDOUT_FILENO, server_reply, n);` where `n` is the length returned by `recv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed the socket at the end of the first iteration. After that, `socket_desc` is no longer a valid filedescriptor.

If you *really* want a new connection every time, the easiest fix is to put the line

```
socket_desc = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0);
```

inside your loop.

As others have said: please check the return values, be prepared to handle cases where not all the reply was received in one go, and fix up the call to printf! Just because this code worked once, does not make it correct.

Comment: Tried that aswell, second interaction program aborts. Implementing error handling now